# Does every locally positive-definite function have a positive-definite extension?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, positivity

Let $B$ denote the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and suppose $f\colon B\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ has the property that for every $n\geq1$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^d$ with $\|x_i-x_j\|<1$, the $n\times n$ matrix $[f(x_i-x_j)]_{ij}$ is positive semidefinite. Can $f$ be extended to a positive definite function over $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true for $d=1$ (M. Krein) but not true for $d>1$ (W. Rudin). For a criterion of extension see

O. Jorgensen,  R. Niedzialomski,
Extension of positive definite functions, 
J. Math. Anal. Appl. 422 (2015), no. 1, 712–740.

Comment: I thought of Rudin's result, but are the hypotheses not slightly different? In the Krein and Rudin results one considers $f$ defined on $\Omega-\Omega$ for some domain $\Omega$

Comment: isn't $B_1=B_{1/2}-B_{1/2}$?

Comment: @PietroMajer Good point, I was being slow. Let me be continue being slow: the framework of Krein and Rudin is that $[f(x_i-x_j)]_{ij}$ should be PSD whenever all the $x_i$ come from $\Omega$. This condition is clearly implied by Dustin's condition; is it clear that they are equivalent?